# polynomials span p2

Tags: linear-algebra

p1 = x^2,
p2 = 1+x,
p3 = 1+x^2
Show that these span P2.

I created a matrix A = \begin{bmatrix}0&1&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&1 \end{bmatrix}
I showed that the determinant$\neq$0. that means AX = 0 is consistent and p1,p2 and p3 are linearly independent.I think this is enough to show that the polynomial span P2 as the dimension of P2 = 3 and we have 3 polynomials.

But my professor put a note that I should argue {p1,p2,p3} is a basis. Then I can say that the polynomials span p2.

To be a basis: the polynomials should be linearly independent and span p2. How can I argue the polynomials are a basis without verifying the span? I am confused over here.

Comment: You are correct that if you have a linearly independent set with cardinality equal to the dimension of the underlying vectorspace, that the given set is a basis. It sounds like your professor wanted you to prove that $\{p_1,p_2,p_2\}$ is a basis for $P_2$ without knowing the dimension beforehand.

Comment: @NoahSolomon This was a test question and it asks to justify if the polynomials span P2. But, to know if the polynomials are a basis the set have to pass the linear independence and span test. I don't think basis can be proved without proving span. Or am i getting something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your question in an actual answer format since that's really where it should go. Lets say we have a vector space $V$ and a set of vectors $\alpha$. By definition, $\alpha$ is a basis if and only if there are linearly independent and span($\alpha) = V$. If you want to show that a given set is a basis, showing that it is linearly independent and spans is a valid method of proving that the given set is in fact a basis. If you already know the dimension of $V$ and $|\alpha| = \dim(v)$, then one only needs to show that $\alpha$ spans $V$ or is linearly independent.

So it is not necessary to prove directly that a given set spans to show that it is a basis, since it can be shown indirectly.